# unity3d couldn't find Android device

Tags: android, build, unity-game-engine

I am doing a unity3d gaming application for android. I have installed unity3d in windows-7. I am creating a sample application. When I execute(showing in screenshot below) my application from unity3d I am getting "couldn't find Android device" error. But I have already connected with the android device. If I execute my application from MAC OS, I can execute it with android device. What may be the problem.

[image: Unity3d Error]

Can someone help me how to fix this?

Comment: check your adb interface device drivers installed correctly!

Comment: go to device manager on your pc and see this screen shot for more details http://i.stack.imgur.com/C5rAc.png

Comment: @Stack Overflow User: Thanks for the response. I will check it.

Comment: Ya its correct. The specific driver not installed in my system. I am using micromax A116 device. But I couldn't found the driver for my device. where can I download it?

Answer (score 2):

try,you are using mmx a116 follow this link download adb interface and try again

http://www.micromaxinfo.com/mobiles/smartphones/canvas/A116-canvas-HD

this download adb interface drivers,user manual pdf file.

Comment: I will check it and let you know.

Comment: I have downloaded the driver software for mmx a116 and installed it in my system. After connected with my device still I am getting the same problem.

Comment: can you enabled usb debugging option on your device?

Comment: Yes I enabled it already. If I run with from MAC OS, it runs on a device(no issues). But the problem found if I connect device with Windows.

Comment: It detected in Device Manager. But it still shows the Exclamation symbol with yellow color.